# Counting number of possible words

Tags: combinatorics

I have alphabet "aaabbc" and maximum word length of 3. I can make 30 words.

In general though if I have an arbitrary alphabet and a maximum word length, how many words can I make?

Comment: For those who haven't seen the revision history of the question: the "alphabet" isn't an alphabet in the usual sense, but instead a multiset of letters, and no letter can be used more often than it occurs in the alphabet. That is, the "alphabet" is more like a bunch of Scrabble tiles.

Comment: I do think this is a reasonable question to ask, and I vote against closing the question.

Comment: To OP: Please restore your example; it makes the question easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

An explicit but not very useful formula would be

$$ \sum_{ c=1}^C  {\sum_{ 0 \le n_i \le N_i \atop  {\sum {n_i}=c}}} \frac{c!}{\prod n_i!} $$

were $C$ is the maximum word length and $N_i$ coutns the available repetitions of each letter.

Java code (not very elegant or efficient): https://ideone.com/4lLX2u

Comment: I get (C=3, N=[3,2,1,5] ) 72 words

Answer (score 0):

You can use generating functions:

In this case, since you have three $a$s, two $b$s, and one $c$, your answer will be the sum of the coefficients of $x^3$ in $$3!(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!})(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!})(1 + x)$$

Edit: Realized that you require words of length at *most* $3$. Then, if the coefficient of $x^2$ is $a$ and the coefficient of $x$ is $b$, add $\frac{a}{3} + \frac{b}{6}$ to the coefficient of $x^3$.

Comment: How familiar are you with generating functions? Here's how it works: Think of expansion of terms as picking one term from each polynomial, because that's really what it is. The first polynomial represents the number of a's you have in your word. If you choose to have 3 a's in the word, you choose the $\frac{x^3}{3!}$ term. It's $x^3$ so at the end, we can know how many letters our word is. It's divided by $3!$ because, since there are three $a$s, we triple count. The same idea is in place for the other two polynomials.

Comment: The $3!$ outside the whole thing is there to represent the permutations of $3$ letters when we choose them. However, since $a$ and $b$ represent only two and one letter, respectively, we divide $a$ by $3$ to get $2!$ and we divide $b$ by $6$ to get $1!$.

Comment: $\frac{3!}{3} = 2!$

Comment: There is a reason. $\frac{3!}{3} = 2!$ (there are two $a$s) and $\frac{3!}{6} = 1!$ (there is one $c$)

Comment: What do oyu mean by $a$ and $b$ divisions? I thought you were referring to the last sentence

Comment: Can you concisely tell me what you mean by $a$ and $b$ divisions? That is extremely vague and I have no idea what that refers to. Does it refer to the $3!$ in the denominator of the first polynomial? Does it refer to the $3$ in $\frac{a}{3}$? I can't help you if I don't know what you don't understand.

Comment: Well, it does work for the general case. It's okay to be skeptical, but this is bordering direspect.

Comment: I told you to clarify what you meant by "a and b divisions", and your comments following did not clarify that, instead you went on about changing the alphabet. Furthermore, as I said before, "I can't help you if I don't know what you don't understand." I have been unable to explain with sufficient detail because I am unable to understand what details you need in the first place.

Comment: Look, don't make this a game of he said she said. After you said that, I said I was mistaken and thought you referred to the $a$ of my last sentence in $\frac{a}{3}$. After asking you to clarify what you meant by a and b divisions, you did not. If you are not going to clarify that, I will not help because I cannot help.

Comment: If you change the alphabet, clearly you would have to change the generating function...

Comment: Since I'm *clearly* intentionally trolling, I regret answering again on your new question.